# RecyclerView populating each item every time i add a new item

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a replica chat app and I have a list that I need populated into the recyclerview. I'm getting data from firebase realtime database and every time I receive or actually send a message, All the previous item(messages) plus the new one are **repopulated/duplicated** into the recycler view.

**What I have tried**
I have tried using `.cleaar()` method on my list before adding a new item to the list but now all other items in the recycler view disappear

here's my adapter

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    public static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
    public static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;


    private Context ctx;
    private List<Messages> msgsR, msgsS;//ignore unused
    private ArrayList<Messages> dataSet;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.ctx = context;
        this.dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        //this.msgsR = messagesReceived;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == Messages.SENT_TYPE) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.message_item_right, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderS(view);
        }
        if (viewType == Messages.RECEIVED_TYPE) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.message_item_left, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderR(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Messages object = dataSet.get(position);
        if (object != null) {
            switch (object.type) {
                case Messages.RECEIVED_TYPE:
                    ((ViewHolderR) holder).populate(object, position);
                    break;
                case Messages.SENT_TYPE:
                    ((ViewHolderS) holder).populate(object, position);
                    break;
            }
        }


    }
//recceives messages object to populate into list
//it does not matter where i put the .clear() method, after or below dataset.add() its still undesireable
    public void addMessageSent(Messages messages){
        dataSet.clear();
        dataSet.add(messages);
       // notifyItemInserted(dataSet.size()-1);
        //notifyItemRangeChanged(dataSet.size()-1, dataSet.size());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    // sent messages are handled here
    public static class ViewHolderS extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView msg, time;
        public LinearLayout layout;

        public ViewHolderS(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont);
            msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.send_msg);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);

        }

        private void populate(Messages messages, int position) {
            msg.setText(messages.getMessage());
            msg.setPadding(6, 4, 18, 4);
            msg.setMinWidth(100);
            msg.setMaxWidth(400);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) msg.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START;
            layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParams.topMargin = layoutParams.bottomMargin = layoutParams.rightMargin = 10;
            layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;

            msg.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            time.setText(messages.getTime());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (dataSet.get(position).type) {
            case 0:
                return Messages.SENT_TYPE;
            case 1:
                return Messages.RECEIVED_TYPE;

            default:
                return -1;
        }

       
    }

// received messages are handled here
    private class ViewHolderR extends ViewHolderS {
        public TextView msg, time;
        public LinearLayout layout;

        public ViewHolderR(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont);
            msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.send_msg);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        }

        private void populate(Messages messages, int position) {

            msg.setText(messages.getMessage());
            msg.setPadding(6, 4, 18, 4);
            msg.setMinWidth(100);
            msg.setMaxWidth(400);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) msg.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.START;
            layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParams.topMargin = layoutParams.bottomMargin = layoutParams.rightMargin = 10;
            layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;

            msg.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            time.setText(messages.getTime());
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my data model

```
public class Messages {
    private String message;
    public static final int SENT_TYPE=0;
    public static final int RECEIVED_TYPE=1;
    public static final int AUDIO_TYPE=2;
    private long time;
    public int type;

    private String id;
    private String receiver;

    public Messages(String message,long time, String sender,String receiver, int type) {
        this.message = message;
        this.time = time;
        this.id = sender;
        this.type = type;
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public Messages() {
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTime() {

        SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        return output.format(new Date(time));
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.id = sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }
}
```

and below is activity class where I set the adapter and fill the list

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

list= new ArrayList();

        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(PersonChatActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

if (Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.getAdapter()).getItemCount() > 0) {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
        }

//get sent messages from firebase
    private void getmessages() {
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Chats");
        reference.keepSynced(true);
        reference.child(senderId).child(receiver).push();
        reference.child(senderId).child(receiver).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                messageSent.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        String message = (String) dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue();
                        long time = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue();
                        String senderId = (String) dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue();
                        String receiverId = (String) dataSnapshot.child("receiver").getValue();
                        assert firebaseUser != null;
                        String user = firebaseUser.getUid();
                        Messages msg = new Messages(message, time, senderId, receiverId,Messages.SENT_TYPE);
                        String Uid = msg.getSender();
                        if (!Uid.isEmpty() && Uid.equals(user)) {
//pass the new message object to messages adapter to fill the list
                           messageAdapter.addMessageSent(msg);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
```

**EDIT UPDATE**

As suggested I have made the necessary changes and code works like magic
I wont update the right changes into the question in case someone makes the same mistake as I have plus the comment marked as answer basically highlights the correct changes,,

**NEW PROBLEM**
The new problem is, on adding object message to the `addMessagesent()`  previously populated recyclerview items get replaced by the new data.

to make it easy, on receiving a new message, all the previous visible **sent messagees** disappear and are replaced by the new **received messages**

here is my `getmessageReceived()` method

```
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Chats");
        reference.keepSynced(true);
        reference.child(receiver).child(senderId).push();
        reference.child(receiver).child(senderId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                messageReceived.clear();
                messageAdapter.clearAllMessage();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        String message = (String) dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue();
                        long time = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue();
                        String senderId = (String) dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue();
                        String receiverId = (String) dataSnapshot.child("receiver").getValue();
                        assert firebaseUser != null;
                        String user = firebaseUser.getUid();
                        Messages msg = new Messages(message, time, senderId, receiverId,Messages.RECEIVED_TYPE);
                        String Uid = msg.getReceiver();
                        if (!Uid.isEmpty() && Uid.equals(user)) {
                            messageAdapter.addMessageSent(msg);
                            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You have to remove .clear() Method in addMessageSent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not clear the data set in the  `addMessageSent()` just add new item to data set as shown below

```
  public void addMessageSent(Messages messages){  
        dataSet.add(messages);
    }
```

and create a new method to clear the dataset in your adapter

```
public void clearAllMessage(){  
            dataSet.clear();
        }
```

And in getmessages() call clearAllMessage() like this

```
private void getmessages() {
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Chats");
        reference.keepSynced(true);
        reference.child(senderId).child(receiver).push();
        reference.child(senderId).child(receiver).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                messageSent.clear();
                 clearAllMessage();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        String message = (String) dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue();
                        long time = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue();
                        String senderId = (String) dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue();
                        String receiverId = (String) dataSnapshot.child("receiver").getValue();
                        assert firebaseUser != null;
                        String user = firebaseUser.getUid();
                        Messages msg = new Messages(message, time, senderId, receiverId,Messages.SENT_TYPE);
                        String Uid = msg.getSender();
                        if (!Uid.isEmpty() && Uid.equals(user)) {
//pass the new message object to messages adapter to fill the list
                           messageAdapter.addMessageSent(msg);
                           messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // Call this also 
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough @AgentP I have been struggling the whole night. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new my upvote is not publicly visible I would have upvoted +100 if only it were possible

Comment: No need to thank @PatrickKariuki .. If my answer worked for you accept my answer.  It does the job

Comment: There will be an accept answer option you can use that ... that is totally fine