# How to stop the RecyclerView OnBindViewHolder() function iterating through all items of my ArrayList every time a new item is added?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a simple chat application for my own learning - no firebase involved (the messages won't be stored between sessions). I've implemented a RecyclerView to show all the messages. The problem is that every time I add a new message, the RecyclerView Adapter will iterate through all previous messages before populating the latest one. Whilst this isn't causing any major bugs, it does seem very inefficient. The relevant functions in my adapter class are shown below:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MessageItem newMsgItem = messages.get(position);
    holder.txtMsgContent.setText(newMsgItem.getMsgContent());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.msgParentView.getLayoutParams();
    if (newMsgItem.isSent()) {
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        holder.msgParentView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        holder.msgParentView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF03DAC5);
    } else {
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        holder.msgParentView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        holder.msgParentView.setCardBackgroundColor(0xFF67706F);
    }
}

// boolean sent: false = received, true = sent
public void addMessage (boolean sent, String msgContent) {
    messages.add(new MessageItem(sent, msgContent));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I could implement a condition-check like below, but that isn't a satisfying solution as it only masks the problem - i.e. the program is still iterating unnecessarily through all previous messages:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position == messages.size() - 1) {
        //... do function
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the program only call onBindViewHolder for the newest item that's been added? I also saw this forum, but as I'm a beginner I couldn't tell if they were having the same issue as me.

[RecyclerView populating each item every time i add a new item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637543/recyclerview-populating-each-item-every-time-i-add-a-new-item)

Answer (score 2):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` always reloads the whole view. Use [notifyItemInserted()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)) instead.

```
public void addMessage (boolean sent, String msgContent) {
    messages.add(new MessageItem(sent, msgContent));
    notifyItemInserted(messages.size()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use notifyDataSetChanged() method, you can use notifyItemInserted() method, this will not refresh every time.

```
public void addMessage (boolean sent, String msgContent) {
messages.add(new MessageItem(sent, msgContent));
notifyItemInserted(messages.size()-1);}
```